# Guardar en la base de datos el SI y No de un botón en html usando javascript teniendo en cuenta el identificador de un campo de la DB

Tags: javascript, html, c#, ajax

Hola estoy pidiendo ayuda por que necesito guardar el **SI** y el **NO** de dos botones que tengo en una vista y que ese **si** y **no** lo agregue a una columna en la base de datos donde ya se grabaron unos datos anteriormente, las etiquetas de los botones son las siguientes

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="si" style="width: 50px;margin:8px" @*onclick="GuardarAprobacion()"*@ id="botonSi">
<span style="color:white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-open"></span>
 SI
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="no" style="width: 50px;margin:8px" @*onclick="GuardarAprobacion()"*@ id="botonNo">
<span style="color:white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-open"></span>
NO
</button>
</div>
```

y el javascript que estoy usando junto ajax para enviar al controlador es el siguiente

```
<script>
  formEventos = document.getElementById("formConsulta");
        formEventos.addEventListener("submit", GuardarAprobado);

        function GuardarAprobado() {
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/GuardarSoporte",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: respuesta,
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.ok) {
                    Swal.fire("Historia guardada!!!!", "La Historia fue guardada exitosamente", "success");
                    setTimeout("location.reload()", 2000)
                } else {
                    Swal.fire("Alerta", "su respuesta no se guardó intentelo nuevamente!!", "warning");
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex.responseText);
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

uno de los problemas principales que tengo es que no me captura el **SI** y el **NO** de los botones  y no tengo idea de como guardar ese valor en el campo de la base de datos teniendo en cuenta el ID de la persona que se registro previamente, usando C#.

Comment: Empieza por el paso uno... primero, respuesta tiene que saber si apreto en si o no.. podrias mandarlo como parametro.. empieza por ahi...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes saber si ha clicado en el botón "si" o en el botón "no" de esta forma:

Remplaza el type='submit' por un

```
// uno para cada boton:

onClick="guardarAprobado('yes')"
onClick="guardarAprobado('no')"
```

A la funcion guardarAprobado le pones el parametro i lo incluyes en respuesta

```
guardarAprobado(selector) {
...
respuesta['selector'] = selector;
...
}
```

P.D. El eventListener entonces te sobra pk ya lo manejas con el onClick